# How can add a splash screen like the below image?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

How can add a splash screen like the below image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbkeV.png)

Comment: Create a photo like this on your editor, then you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Answer (score 1):

You can blue any image and then write any text on that using Stack

Refer This website :
[Blure Splash Screen Medium](https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73)